# Confusion regarding notation/symbol?

Tags: discrete-signals, convolution, terminology

I was reading circular convolution topic from *Digital Signal Processing Using Matlab*  3rd Ed,by Proakis. I came across a strange term/symbol; I have highlighted it in attached snapshot

**Update:Pg150; same chapter,same book(just before example 5.4) contains this notation and mentions that it is a rectangular window of length N**

I have also attached snap of eq 5.24,in 2nd snap, where this RN(n) symbol appears also:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you give a little more context on the topic being explained here? By looking at just this I can only imagine that this term represents $n^{th}$ component of a Vector in N dimension, usually represented as $\mathcal{R}^N$

Comment: Proakis / edited multiple books, in multiple revisions. Which one is this, which page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This symbol denotes a rectangular pulse of length $N$:

$$\mathcal{R}_N(n)=\begin{cases}1,&0\le n\le N-1\\0,&\textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

I'm not sure where it is defined for the first time, but this definition is clear from the equation above Eq. $(5.24)$ on page $130$ of the 3rd edition of *Digital Signal Processing Using Matlab* by V.K. Ingle and J.G. Proakis.

Comment: I have attached snap of eq 5.24 ,but sorry for that equation is bit different from your

Comment: @engr: I don't see how it's different. If you interpret $\mathcal{R}_N(n)$ as in my answer, it matches exactly the equation given in the book.

Comment: Because apparently the equation involves product of  RN(n)  & X(k) .  Beacuse RN(n) is not alone

Comment: @engr: That's right, but from the equation you can infer what is meant by that symbol.

Comment: Yes, i understood, that is why, i clicked accept answer